# How do I set a variable in MySql so that is will not get reset during my query?

Tags: mysql, variables

My variables are set like this:

```
SET @start_date = '2015-07-20';
SET @end_date = '2016-06-30';
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.school_id, COUNT(a.log_id) logs
FROM table1 a
JOIN tbl2 b ON a.log_id = b.log_id
JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE  DATE(log_date) BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND b.column2 = 123
GROUP BY a.user_id, b.school_id;
```

Tables 1 and 2 are both very very large tables, so the query takes a very long time to run, which is fine for my purposes. The issue is that my variables somehow get reset during the query, so the results come back empty. My question is, is there any way to set the variables so that they will not time out during the queries?

Any ideas would really be appreciated!

Comment: Session variables don't reset themselves, they should persist for the lifetime of the connection.

Comment: I tested with plugging in the actual dates instead of using variables and it returned results, so something is happening to the variables during the query. If i try running SELECT @start_date after the query returns an empty set, it returns NULL.

Comment: That would usually indicate your connection is being reset; a normal `SELECT` that does not assign to the variables should not be affecting their values. How are you executing the sets and query?

Comment: I am using sql yog.

Comment: I can't think of what could be resetting your variables, but perhaps speeding up the query would help. Do you have the `log_id` fields in table1 and tbl2, and the `user_id` in table1 and users, indexed? Also, which table is `log_date` from, and what kind of data is in it? _If it is a datetime and indexed, using @start_date and @end_date values that include time and doing `log_date BETWEEN ...`, instead of `DATE(log_date) BETWEEN ...` may help._

Comment: Log id is indexed in both tables and user id is indexed in table1, log_date is from table1 and is indexed as well. I will try using time stamps for my variables and see if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is a weird problem.
If you optimize your query to run faster, the issue might be resolved. Use 'AND' rather than 'WHERE' when you join your big tables:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.school_id, COUNT(a.log_id) logs FROM table1 a JOIN tbl2 b ON a.log_id = b.log_id JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.user_id AND DATE(log_date) BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date AND b.column2 = 123 GROUP BY a.user_id, b.school_id;
```

Comment: You can replace 'DATE(log_date)' with a date column (a new column) to apply indexes and possibly partitions to have your query run quite faster. Moreover, you can replace 'WHERE' with 'AND' to be surprised of the performance gain.